# PHP 7 Too few arguments in a function that takes no arguments

Tags: php-7

I'm working on updating my code to be PHP 7 compatible, and the "Too few arguments" error is a common one that I've been fixing. I can't seem to figure out why it is happening with this function, though:

```
function processDates(){
    global $post;
    if(get_field('seminar_end_date')){
        $datestart = get_field('seminar_start_date');
        $dateend = get_field('seminar_end_date');
        if($datestart == $dateend){
            return date('M j, Y',strtotime($datestart));
        } else {
            $daterange = combineDates($datestart,$dateend);
            return $daterange;
        }
    } else {
        $daterange = '<strong>Wk 1:
</strong>'.combineDates(get_field('weekend_1_start'),get_field('weekend_1_end'));
        if(get_field('weekend_2_start')) $daterange .= '<br /><strong>Wk 2:</strong> '.combineDates(get_field('weekend_2_start'),get_field('weekend_2_end'));
        if(get_field('weekend_3_start')) $daterange .= '<br /><strong>Wk 3:</strong> '.combineDates(get_field('weekend_3_start'),get_field('weekend_3_end'));
        if(get_field('weekend_4_start')) $daterange .= '<br /><strong>Wk 4:</strong> '.combineDates(get_field('weekend_4_start'),get_field('weekend_4_end'));
        //if(!get_field('weekend_4_start') && (get_field('seminar_category') == 'LifeWorks')) $daterange .='<br /><strong>Wk 4:</strong> TBA';
        return $daterange;
    }
}

$semdates = processDates();
```

As far as I can tell, the function doesn't expect any arguments to be passed to it.

Thanks for any help or nudges in the right direction.

Here's the error message it generates:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function processDates(), 0 passed in /page-SeminarCalendar.php on line 123 and exactly 3 expected in /page-SeminarCalendar.php:69

Comment: Can you pls post the *exact* error message, rather than just mention you get an error?

Comment: I've edited to included the error message in the original post.

Comment: What exactly is line 123 in page-SeminarCalendar.php? What exactly is in line 69 in page-SeminarCalendar.php?

Comment: Looks to me like the processDates method in /page-SeminarCalendar.php is not the one you posted above. Can you verify that. Also verify there are no other processDates methods around the place.

Comment: All of the above code is located in page-SeminarCalendar.php, and line 123 is the function call (last line posted above), line 69 the function declaration (first line posted above). I removed some other code in between, as it's mostly other variable declarations. I can post it, too, though, if y'all think it would help.

Comment: OK. Are you *certain* the version of the code yer running is the same code yer looking at? You've not forgotten to deploy it, or something like that? Change the name of the function in its declaration. Does the error message change equivalently?

Comment: @AdamCameron is on the right track. Somehow that is not the function you're calling.....

Comment: Okay, thank you all for your feedback and suggestions. I'll dive deeper and see if I can get clearer on what's going on, but I'm glad it's not something simple I'm overlooking in the transition to PHP 7. I'll post back with my findings.